# Shimming a class instantiated by a static class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I have a static class which creates a database class instance. I am looking for a way to shim/stub that database class in my tests.

```
public partial class Y : Form
{
    static Models.DBModel db = new Models.DBModel();
    ....
```

Unfortunately I cannot change the code. Is there any way I can mock this database class in my tests?

Comment: If the call to this variable goes through one method then you could override this method. Othervise, you could try to use some special frameworks like [TypeMock](http://www.typemock.com/) or [Fakes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I am using Fakes! Sorry, someone removed this information from the topic title. I was asking for a way to do it through fakes. I tried creating a DB shim before instantiating the static class, but the DB instance created by the static class doesn't use the shim.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see - information about Microsoft Fakes was moved to the tag.  Is it a private field? Can you change it to protected and then you can override this class and initialize this field in the construnctor.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

I. Update `yourdll.fakes` to include:

```
...
<ShimGeneration>
    <Clear/>
    ...
    <Add FullName="Models.DBModel"/>
    ...
</ShimGeneration>
...
```

II. In your `TestClass` create method with `[TestInitialize]` and `[TestCleanup]` attribute:

```
using Models.Fakes;

IDisposable shimsContext;

[TestInitialize]
public void SetUp()
{
    shimsContext = ShimsContext.Create();
    ShimDBModel.Constructor = (@this) =>
    {
        ShimDBModel shim = new ShimDBModel(@this)
        {
            // here you can provide shim methods for DBModel
        };
    };
}

[TestCleanup]
public void CleanUp()
{
    // Let's do not forget to clean up shims after each test runs
    shimsContext.Dispose();
}
```

III. And finally in your test, the `Y.db` should be *Shim* created in  `SetUp` method.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    Y.db... // db should be shim
}
```

Comment: Can someone provide an example of how to write "// here you can provide shim methods for DBModel"